# how to print 2 or 4 bytes in hex format in C

Tags: c, hex, byte, printf, endianness

I need to print bytes in `hexadecimal` form in `C`. All I’ve managed to do is to print 1 byte at a time, where my program has to support the option for 1, 2 or 4 bytes (size parameter).
this is my function:

```
void memDisaply(char* filename, int size) {

char sentence [100];
unsigned int str[20];
int length,i;
unsigned char* ptr;

printf("Please enter <address> <length>\n");

fflush(stdin);
fgets(sentence,100,stdin);
fgets(sentence,100,stdin);

    sscanf (sentence,"%x %d",str,&length);
    ptr = (unsigned char*)str;

    for (i=0 ; i< length ; i++) {
        printf ("%02x",(unsigned int)ptr[i]);
    }

    /*reset values*/
    length = 0;
    i = 0;
    ptr = NULL;
}
```

the output is as follows (where size=1, and length= 10):

```
31 ED 5E 89 E1 83 E4 F0 50 54
```

I need that when `size = 2` and `length = 5` that the output will be:

```
ED31 895E 83E1 F0E4 5450
```

(notice the `little endian`)
I somehow need to use the size argument to alter the output but I don't know how.
I assume it got something to do with the `%02x` format, and I've tried `%04x` but all I got was:

```
0031 00ED 005E 0089 00E1 0083 00E4 00F0 0050 0054
```

Comment: I do not believe your output matches the code. You have spaces in the output but not in the format string.

Comment: you're right i did forgot a space but that wasn't the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read two bytes by two bytes and do:

```
printf ("%04x", (unsigned int) ptr[i] | (unsigned int) ptr[i + 1] << 8);
```

Comment: first of all, thanks! now, if size is 1 the output is (diffrent from before i know but it's related to something else): 70 85 04 08 a7 e2 81 ff a7 e2, but with size 2 and the line you suggested i get: 8570 0485 0804 a708 72a7. maybe i didn't understood fully what you meant by read two bytes by two bytes? can you explain further please?

Comment: @nadavbara what I mean is in the `printf` statement I'm accessing to `ptr[i]` and `ptr[i + 1]`, so in you `for` loop you also have to change `i++` and `i += 2`.